# Tag synonym of [number-theory]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I have proposed [diophantine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diophantine) as a synonym of [number-theory](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory). [Here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/number-theory/synonyms) is the link to it. Please vote for it.

Answer (score 7):

The [Help Center](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) says about tag synonyms:

> #### When should I propose a tag synonym?
>
> Whenever you see questions being repeatedly tagged with the wrong or incorrect tag -- or multiple tags that mean the same thing -- it's a good idea to propose a tag synonym.

The tag was only used *once*, not repeatedly, so I've chosen the more pragmatic way of editing the [question where it was used](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/101429/11110). Pending tag synonyms don't get a lot of attention, because there is no review queue or something for them.